# SFMC marketing cloud - subject line contains special characters not showing up

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I am trying to send an email with the following text in the subject text:

A closet refresh is calling

with this subject text, the SFMC UI is not able to show the subject.

Any help on how to handle such special characters in the subject would be greatly appreciated.

I was sending the mail through data integrations and i was seeing this UI

[image]

we are using the following API for sending the email: https://webservice.s10.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx

I was looking for a solution to send the subject in the API so that the subject text is shown correctly.

Any help on this would be helpful. Thanks

Thanks,
Ravi Gopalan

Comment: What is the payload you are using?

Comment: we are creating a soap_message with the envelop containing the attributes HTML__Content and Subject. I don't have the exact payload but it is basically constructing a soap envelop with appropriate attributes.

Comment: I see the value in the DE, are you saying that in test sends, etc. it is not showing, or are you going off just the value displayed in the DE?

Comment: As a note, I did a test send using your displayed subject and it came out with correct content expected. (Once I figured out which were capital `i` and which were lowercase `l`, lol)

Comment: @Gortonington I wonder if you need to decode it before the send? I tried to decode it and it says something like Hurry almost sold out

Answer (score 1):

Change the target language to `Unicode-UTF-8` will make it work

From Content Builder, you go to your email and switch to Properties tab, at the right side it will have an option like this:

[image]

Make sure you selected `Unicode-UTF-8`

Test result when I try to send to my inbox:
[image]

Comment: The target language section is only for the email body, and has no effect on the subjectline directly.